# Hibernate + SQLite not creating database

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, javafx

Here's my problem:

I have a desktop application using JavaFX + Hibernate + SQLite.
This is my Model:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario implements AbstractModel, Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull @Size(min=5, max=100)
    private String username;

    @NotNull @Size(min=5, max=100)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean administrador;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public Usuario(Integer id, String username, String password, Boolean admin, Integer version) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.administrador = admin;
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPasword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Boolean getAdministrador() {
        return administrador;
    }

    public void setAdministrador(Boolean administrador) {
        this.administrador = administrador;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
```

This is my persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PartyRockPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>br.com.gear7.partyrock.model.Usuario</class>

    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:party_rock.sqlite" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="br.com.gear7.partyrock.utils.SQLiteDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And finally this is my SQLiteDialect

```
> package br.com.gear7.partyrock.utils;
/*
 * The author disclaims copyright to this source code. In place of
 * a legal notice, here is a blessing:
 * 
 * May you do good and not evil.
 * May you find forgiveness for yourself and forgive others.
 * May you share freely, never taking more than you give.
 *
 */
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.VarArgsSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {
    public SQLiteDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
        registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
        registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
        registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
        registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
        registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
        registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric");
        registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
        registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
        registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
        // registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null");
        registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "integer");

        registerFunction("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "",
                "||", ""));
        registerFunction("mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate(org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER,
                "?1 % ?2"));
        registerFunction("substr", new StandardSQLFunction("substr",
                org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
        registerFunction("substring", new StandardSQLFunction("substr",
                org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
    }

    public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
        return true;
    }

    /*
     public boolean supportsInsertSelectIdentity() {
     return true; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
     }
     */

    public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
        return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
    }

    /*
     public String appendIdentitySelectToInsert(String insertString) {
     return new StringBuffer(insertString.length()+30). // As specify in NHibernate dialect
     append(insertString).
     append("; ").append(getIdentitySelectString()).
     toString();
     }
     */

    public String getIdentityColumnString() {
        // return "integer primary key autoincrement";
        return "integer";
    }

    public String getIdentitySelectString() {
        return "select last_insert_rowid()";
    }

    public boolean supportsLimit() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getLimitString(String query, boolean hasOffset) {
        return new StringBuffer(query.length() + 20).append(query).append(
                hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?").toString();
    }

    public boolean supportsTemporaryTables() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getCreateTemporaryTableString() {
        return "create temporary table if not exists";
    }

    public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean supportsCurrentTimestampSelection() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getCurrentTimestampSelectString() {
        return "select current_timestamp";
    }

    public boolean supportsUnionAll() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasAlterTable() {
        return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
    }

    public boolean dropConstraints() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getAddColumnString() {
        return "add column";
    }

    public String getForUpdateString() {
        return "";
    }

    public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "No drop foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName,
            String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable, String[] primaryKey,
            boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "No add foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "No add primary key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
        return true;

}
    public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I run my application, everything goes smoothly but the database file doesn't get created, meaning that my table also doesn't get created.

Been struggling with this for the past 3 hours and can't find any solution for it.

Comment: I also have the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Comment: which platform you used for write code and version ?

Comment: Finally did you resolved your problem ? If yes, can you share the solution ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry it took so long, but I got into a different project and had to travel abroad for a while. But yes, I remember this and I found a solution. The problem was on the DIALECT I was using. I'm using a new one with the UPDATE value on the persistence.xml It works fine for me now. If you wan I can post my new Dialect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry it took me so long, but here is what solved the problem for me. I changed the DIALECT file to a better one that I found.

```
package gear7.partyrock.utils;

/*
 * The author disclaims copyright to this source code.  In place of
 * a legal notice, here is a blessing:
 *
 *    May you do good and not evil.
 *    May you find forgiveness for yourself and forgive others.
 *    May you share freely, never taking more than you give.
 *
 */

import java.sql.Types;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;

import org.hibernate.dialect.function.AbstractAnsiTrimEmulationFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.NoArgSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.VarArgsSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {
  public SQLiteDialect() {
    registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "boolean");
    registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
    registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
    registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
    registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
    registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
    registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
    registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
    registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric($p, $s)");
    registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
    registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
    registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar($l)");
    registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
    registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime");
    registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
    registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "boolean");

    //registerFunction( "abs", new StandardSQLFunction("abs") );
    registerFunction( "concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "", "||", "") );
    //registerFunction( "length", new StandardSQLFunction("length", StandardBasicTypes.LONG) );
    //registerFunction( "lower", new StandardSQLFunction("lower") );
    registerFunction( "mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "?1 % ?2" ) );
    registerFunction( "quote", new StandardSQLFunction("quote", StandardBasicTypes.STRING) );
    registerFunction( "random", new NoArgSQLFunction("random", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER) );
    registerFunction( "round", new StandardSQLFunction("round") );
    registerFunction( "substr", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StandardBasicTypes.STRING) );
    registerFunction( "substring", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "substr(?1, ?2, ?3)" ) );
    registerFunction( "trim", new AbstractAnsiTrimEmulationFunction() {
        protected SQLFunction resolveBothSpaceTrimFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?1)");
        }

        protected SQLFunction resolveBothSpaceTrimFromFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?2)");
        }

        protected SQLFunction resolveLeadingSpaceTrimFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "ltrim(?1)");
        }

        protected SQLFunction resolveTrailingSpaceTrimFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "rtrim(?1)");
        }

        protected SQLFunction resolveBothTrimFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?1, ?2)");
        }

        protected SQLFunction resolveLeadingTrimFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "ltrim(?1, ?2)");
        }

        protected SQLFunction resolveTrailingTrimFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "rtrim(?1, ?2)");
        }
    } );
    //registerFunction( "upper", new StandardSQLFunction("upper") );
  }

  public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
    return true;
  }

  /*
  public boolean supportsInsertSelectIdentity() {
    return true; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
  }
  */

  public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
    return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
  }

  /*
  public String appendIdentitySelectToInsert(String insertString) {
    return new StringBuffer(insertString.length()+30). // As specify in NHibernate dialect
      append(insertString).
      append("; ").append(getIdentitySelectString()).
      toString();
  }
  */

  public String getIdentityColumnString() {
    // return "integer primary key autoincrement";
    return "integer";
  }

  public String getIdentitySelectString() {
    return "select last_insert_rowid()";
  }

  public boolean supportsLimit() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean bindLimitParametersInReverseOrder() {
    return true;
  }

  protected String getLimitString(String query, boolean hasOffset) {
    return new StringBuffer(query.length()+20).
      append(query).
      append(hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?").
      toString();
  }

  public boolean supportsTemporaryTables() {
    return true;
  }

  public String getCreateTemporaryTableString() {
    return "create temporary table if not exists";
  }

  public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
    return true; // TODO Validate
  }

  public boolean supportsCurrentTimestampSelection() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean isCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable() {
    return false;
  }

  public String getCurrentTimestampSelectString() {
    return "select current_timestamp";
  }

  public boolean supportsUnionAll() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean hasAlterTable() {
    return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
  }

  public boolean dropConstraints() {
    return false;
  }

  /*
  public String getAddColumnString() {
    return "add column";
  }
  */

  public String getForUpdateString() {
    return "";
  }

  public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No drop foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
  }

  public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName,
      String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable, String[] primaryKey,
      boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
  }

  public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add primary key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
  }

  public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
    return true;
  }

  /* not case insensitive for unicode characters by default (ICU extension needed)
  public boolean supportsCaseInsensitiveLike() {
    return true;
  }
  */

  public boolean supportsTupleDistinctCounts() {
    return false;
  }

  public String getSelectGUIDString() {
    return "select hex(randomblob(16))";
  }
}
```

And I changed this line on my persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

This solved for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code can you store things the database?

Looking at your persistence.xml I can see `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>` which will create a DB when hibernates start-up then delete it when hibernate shuts down. It could easily be that the DB is being created but the Hibernate dropping the DB is removing it.

Comment: I already tried with create-update, update, validate, create and other possible values.. none work

Answer (score 0):

Just add this
    < property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create< /property>
in persistence.xml. It will work. But other-than create is not working.