# SpringMVC Hibernate + SQLite not creating database

Tags: spring, sqlite, spring-mvc, hibernate-4.x

I am trying to use Hibernate and SQLite in a spring MVC project, I have configurated my project and when I run it on server, the dataBase is not created and I can't connect or use the sqlite database.

THere is no exception wthen the server start and I'm using the entity Manager with Hibernate4.

persistence.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

 <!-- Load database property file -->

 <bean
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location">
   <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <!-- Create datasource bean -->

 <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:franchise.db" />
  <property name="username" value="" />
  <property name="password" value="" />
 </bean>


 <!-- Create Entity manager - JPA -->

 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.binov.franchise.model.*" />

  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
  </property>

  <property name="jpaProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>

 </bean>

   <tx:annotation-driven />

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
 </bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
 <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

```html
pom.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>com.binov</groupId>
     <artifactId>franchise</artifactId>
     <name>ProjectFranchise</name>
     <packaging>war</packaging>
     <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

      <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>

      <jackson-version>1.9.13</jackson-version>

      <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>

      <!-- <iresolve-core.mysql-connector-java>5.1.14</iresolve-core.mysql-connector-java> -->

      <iresolve-core.hibernate-entitymanager-version>3.6.0.Final</iresolve-core.hibernate-entitymanager-version>

      <iresolve-core.hibernate-validator.version>5.1.3.Final</iresolve-core.hibernate-validator.version>


      <iresolve-core.aspectj.version>1.5.4</iresolve-core.aspectj.version>

      <iresolve-core.junit.version>4.9</iresolve-core.junit.version>

      <iresolve-core.org.springframework.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</iresolve-core.org.springframework.version>


      <iresolve-core.org.springframework-security-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</iresolve-core.org.springframework-security-version>


      <iresolve-core.javassist.version>3.3</iresolve-core.javassist.version>

      <org.tiles-version>3.0.3</org.tiles-version>



     </properties>


     <dependencies>


      <!-- Logging dependencies slf4j -->

      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
       <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.16</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>



      <!-- Javassist for PROXY Solution -->

      <dependency>
       <groupId>javassist</groupId>
       <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.javassist.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- image decode -->
      <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
       <version>1.9</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Hibernate -->
      

      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.hibernate-entitymanager-version}</version>
       <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
         <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.hibernate-entitymanager-version}</version>
       <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
         <groupId>asm</groupId>
         <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
         <groupId>asm</groupId>
         <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
         <groupId>cglib</groupId>
         <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
         <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
         <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>

       </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      
      <!-- Dependencies for Hibernate and ORM  -->  
      <dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.156</version>
      </dependency>
     

      <!-- Dependencies for SQLite -->
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
       <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.11.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- <dependency>
       <groupId>net.kemitix</groupId>
       <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
       <version>0.1.0</version>
      </dependency> --> 
            
             <!-- SQLite JDBC library 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
                <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.11.2</version>
            </dependency>-->

      <!-- JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->

      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.hibernate-validator.version}</version>

      </dependency>
      <!-- Jsoooooon -->
      <dependency>
       <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
       <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
       <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.json</groupId>
       <artifactId>json</artifactId>
       <version>20150729</version>
      </dependency>


      <!-- **************************** Spring ***************************************** -->

      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.org.springframework.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.org.springframework.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.org.springframework.version}</version>


       <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
         <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
       </exclusions>


      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.org.springframework.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.org.springframework.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.org.springframework.version}</version>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.org.springframework.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- postgres connector 
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
       <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
       <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
      </dependency>-->

      <!-- Spring Security -->


      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.org.springframework-security-version}</version>
       <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
         <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.org.springframework-security-version}</version>
       <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
         <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.org.springframework-security-version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.org.springframework-security-version}</version>
       <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
         <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
      </dependency>




      <!-- AspectJ -->
      <dependency>
       <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
       <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.aspectj.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
       <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.aspectj.version}</version>
      </dependency>


      <!-- Commons utilities Dependencies -->



      <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.0</version>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
       <version>3.0</version>
      </dependency>



      <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
       <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
       <version>1.1</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>


      <!-- @Inject -->
      <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
       <version>1</version>
      </dependency>


      <!-- Servlet -->
      <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.5</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.1</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>jstl</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Apache Tiles -->

      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
       <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
       <version>${org.tiles-version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Jackson JSON Processor -->


      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.13</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.13</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
       <version>2.4.3</version>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
       <version>${iresolve-core.org.springframework.version}</version>
      </dependency>



      <dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>4.4</version>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
       <version>2.5</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
       <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.7</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- jsonEncoder Pom -->

      <dependency>
       <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
       <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
       <version>2.0</version>
      </dependency>
     </dependencies>


     <build>
      <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
         <additionalProjectnatures>
          <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
         </additionalProjectnatures>
         <additionalBuildcommands>
          <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
         </additionalBuildcommands>
         <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
         <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
         <source>1.6</source>
         <target>1.6</target>
         <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
         <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
         <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
         <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
      </plugins>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
     </build>
    </project>
```

```js
SQLiteDialect.java

    package org.hibernate.dialect;



    import java.sql.Types;

    import org.hibernate.dialect.function.AbstractAnsiTrimEmulationFunction;
    import org.hibernate.dialect.function.NoArgSQLFunction;
    import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction;
    import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
    import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
    import org.hibernate.dialect.function.VarArgsSQLFunction;
    import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

    public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {
      public SQLiteDialect() {
        registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
        registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
        registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
        registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
        registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
        registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
        registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric");
        registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
        registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
        registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
        // registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null");
        registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "boolean");

        registerFunction( "concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "", "||", "") );
        registerFunction( "mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "?1 % ?2" ) );
        registerFunction( "quote", new StandardSQLFunction("quote", StandardBasicTypes.STRING) );
        registerFunction( "random", new NoArgSQLFunction("random", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER) );
        registerFunction( "round", new StandardSQLFunction("round") );
        registerFunction( "substr", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StandardBasicTypes.STRING) );
        registerFunction( "trim", new AbstractAnsiTrimEmulationFunction() {
            protected SQLFunction resolveBothSpaceTrimFunction() {
              return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?1)");
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveBothSpaceTrimFromFunction() {
              return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?2)");
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveLeadingSpaceTrimFunction() {
              return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "ltrim(?1)");
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveTrailingSpaceTrimFunction() {
              return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "rtrim(?1)");
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveBothTrimFunction() {
              return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?1, ?2)");
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveLeadingTrimFunction() {
              return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "ltrim(?1, ?2)");
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveTrailingTrimFunction() {
              return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "rtrim(?1, ?2)");
            }
        } );
      }

      public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
        return true;
      }

      /*
      public boolean supportsInsertSelectIdentity() {
        return true; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
      }
      */

      public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
        return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
      }

      /*
      public String appendIdentitySelectToInsert(String insertString) {
        return new StringBuffer(insertString.length()+30). // As specify in NHibernate dialect
          append(insertString).
          append("; ").append(getIdentitySelectString()).
          toString();
      }
      */

      public String getIdentityColumnString() {
        // return "integer primary key autoincrement";
        return "integer";
      }

      public String getIdentitySelectString() {
        return "select last_insert_rowid()";
      }

      public boolean supportsLimit() {
        return true;
      }

      protected String getLimitString(String query, boolean hasOffset) {
        return new StringBuffer(query.length()+20).
          append(query).
          append(hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?").
          toString();
      }

      public boolean supportsTemporaryTables() {
        return true;
      }

      public String getCreateTemporaryTableString() {
        return "create temporary table if not exists";
      }

      public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
        return false;
      }

      public boolean supportsCurrentTimestampSelection() {
        return true;
      }

      public boolean isCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable() {
        return false;
      }

      public String getCurrentTimestampSelectString() {
        return "select current_timestamp";
      }

      public boolean supportsUnionAll() {
        return true;
      }

      public boolean hasAlterTable() {
        return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
      }

      public boolean dropConstraints() {
        return false;
      }

      public String getAddColumnString() {
        return "add column";
      }

      public String getForUpdateString() {
        return "";
      }

      public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
        return false;
      }

      public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No drop foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
      }

      public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName,
          String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable, String[] primaryKey,
          boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
      }

      public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add primary key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
      }

      public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
        return true;
      }

      public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After changing the SQLite dialect (like here [Hibernate + SQLite not creating database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397677/hibernate-sqlite-not-creating-database?answertab=active#tab-top)) and reference it correctly:

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.mypackaged.dialect.SQLiteDialect</prop>
```

and changing the hbm2ddl.auto propery to "update":

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

... have you tried to put an absolute URL (with W / R permissions) in your JDBC URL property?

For example:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:c:\\franchise.db" /> (in Windows)
```

Check if the database was created on the right path (C:/franchise.db).